# Holomorhic function has no zeroes

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ is holomorphic in unit disk $D$ and $|f(z)| < 1$ for all $z \in D, f(0)=a\ne0$. Prove that $f(z)\ne 0$ if $|z|<|a|$.

It seems that maximum module theorem can be used, but I'm completely stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know [Schwarz-Pick Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem), which is a corollary of the Maximum Modulus Principle, then your exercise is trivial.

Suppose that there exists a $z_0\in D$ such that $f(z_0)=0$. Then, by Schwarz-Pick Theorem applied to $0$ and $z_0$, we get $|a|\leq |z_0|$.